# Xamarin.Forms - Strange height issue with my responsive WebViews on iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, wkwebview

I have a ListView and inside that I want to bind multiple webviews which all vary in height. I want to calculate the height of each webview based on it's content and display it accordingly.

It works on Android - on iOS all WebViews are FAR too big

```
       await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100);
       var result = (double)webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height;
       _webView.HeightRequest = result;
```

The strange thing is: the MORE html characters the webview has, the bigger it gets. So I could add just one character and another 50px will be added to the height.

It is a lot of code to post here but here is a link to the project on github:
https://github.com/SlimboTimbo/MultipleWebViews

Comment: Hi , thanks for sharing sample project link here . That's will be helpful to find the solution . I will check that in my local site :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the project , have found the reason why not works in iOS Device .

The **reason** is that the `width` of `webView.ScrollView.ContentSize` is not correct , is too small that is 27 . Therefore , it can not show correctly .

```
System.Console.WriteLine("----" + resultWidth + "-----"+ resultHeight + "----"+ _webView.Width);
```

**Output** :

```
2020-06-04 11:19:58.066542+0800 MultipleWebViews.iOS[50674:1690400] ----27-----642----375
```

**Solution** :

You can caluculate the `height` by the width of `HybridWebView`, and set the calcualted `height` for `HybridWebView` .

**DidFinishNavigation** method code as follow :

```
public override async void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
{

    try
    {
        var _webView = webViewRenderer.Element as HybridWebView;
        if (_webView != null)
        {
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100);
            var resultWidth = (double)webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Width;
            var resultHeight = (double)webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height;
            System.Console.WriteLine("----" + resultWidth + "-----"+ resultHeight + "----"+ _webView.Width);

            double result = MeasureTextHeightSize(_webView.messageContent, _webView.Width, UIFont.LabelFontSize, null);

            _webView.HeightRequest = result;

            MessagingCenter.Send<Object, PassModel>(this, "LoadFinished", new PassModel(_webView.Id, Convert.ToDouble(result)));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error at HybridWebViewRenderer LoadingFinished: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**MeasureTextHeightSize** ( Calculate the height method )

```
private double MeasureTextHeightSize(string text, double width, double fontSize, string fontName = null)
{
    var nsText = new NSString(text);
    var boundSize = new SizeF((float)width, float.MaxValue);
    var options = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading | NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin;

    if (fontName == null)
    {
        fontName = "HelveticaNeue";
    }

    var attributes = new UIStringAttributes
    {
        Font = UIFont.FromName(fontName, (float)fontSize)
    };

    var sizeF = nsText.GetBoundingRect(boundSize, options, attributes, null).Size;

    //return new Xamarin.Forms.Size((double)sizeF.Width, (double)sizeF.Height);
    return (double)sizeF.Height;
}
```

The **Effect** :

[image]

**Note** : You can modify the `fontSize` of this method according to your current system font size . And also can custom the return value ,such as `return (double)sizeF.Height + 10` to fit screen .

Comment: Perfect! 

Unfortunately, I still have an issue once I start wrapping html content into divs. It again adds a huge amount of unnecessary spacing.

I can recheck it all into github if needed

Comment: @TJP Okey , you can update it in github , I will check that . In addition ,remember to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue !

Comment: I have updated it now with more complex HTML, it once again seems to negatively affect the height created.

Comment: @TJP Thanks for updating , I will check that .

Comment: @TJP If contains `div` , the solution can not always works . Although can use `if ... else ...` to know whether contain `div` , but this way will not works all the time . Because the style of  `div` can be different . I will continue to find the best slution , if good news will update here .

Comment: One thing I can do is wrap the html in a div with an ID (wrapper) and then use:

await _webView.EvaluateJavascriptAsync("document.getElementById('wrapper').scrollHeight");

And assign this to the HeightRequest. It seems to work but I am not sure if this is good practice?

Comment: @TJP That's a good idea . However , that needs `Html` conatin a `ID` , and this requires setting the outermost div . If forget to sett, it will not work .  This can be a solution now .